# Javascript/jQuery animation load in next image

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I am working on an assignment where we need to create an animation where the image slides, is hidden, then will load in the next image.

I have the animation and hide function working properly, I just cannot figure out how to load in the next image with its correlating title. Here is the code I have so far. Would it be correct to hide the image and load in the next image in the callback function or would I have to create a whole separate function to display the next image

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#image_list a").each(function() {
     // get the image URL and caption for each image
     var imageURL = $(this).attr("href");
     var caption = $(this).attr("title");
        var slideNode = $("image_list");
        //var images = 
     

     // preload the image for each link  
  var galleryImage = new Image();
  galleryImage.src = imageURL;
  
  // set up the event handlers for each link
  $(this).click(function(evt) {
   $("#image").attr("src", imageURL);
      $("#caption").text(caption);
       //$("#image").hide();
           //$("#image").animate({marginLeft: "-=100px"});
           
            $("#image").animate({
            //opacity: 0.25,
            marginLeft: "-=100px",
            //height: "toggle"
            }, 2000, function() {
            // Animation complete.
            $("#image").hide();
            //load in next image after animation 
            imageCounter = (imageCounter + 1) % imageURL.length;  
            //galleryImage.src = imageURL[imageCounter];
            //caption = 
            }); 





      // cancel the default action of each link
      evt.preventDefault();
    }); // end click 
    }); // end each
    // move the focus to the first link
    $("li:first-child a").focus();
}); // end ready
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 420px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}
h1, h2, ul, p {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
h1 {
 padding-bottom: .25em;
 color: blue;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 120%;
 padding: .5em 0;
}
li {
 padding: 0 0.25em;
 display: inline;
}
#caption, #gallery {
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="image_gallery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<main>
    <h1>Image Gallery</h1>
    <ul id="image_list">
        <li><a href="casting1.jpg" title="Casting on the Upper Kings">Upper Kings</a></li>
        <li><a href="casting2.jpg" title="Casting on the Lower Kings">Lower Kings</a></li>
        <li><a href="catchrelease.jpg" title="Catch and Release on the Big Horn">Big Horn</a></li>
        <li><a href="fish.jpg" title="Catching on the South Fork">South Fork</a></li>
        <li><a href="lures.jpg" title="The Lures for Catching">Lures</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h2 id="caption">Casting on the Upper Kings</h2>
    <p id="gallery">
     <img src="casting1.jpg" alt="Image Gallery area" id="image">
    </p>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what is the animation you wish to achieve... But here is what I think it is *(run the snippet)*.

I think you wish to change the image URL and its caption while it's hidden. Here, I prefered the `.fadeOut()` and `.fadeIn()` effects. Because there is no "sizing" animation like in `.hide()` and `.show()`. That is about taste.

I think the image fading should be done in the animation callback (after the slight move to the left)... **Then,** in the `.fadeOut()` callback (When the image is completely hidden), you can change the image and caption. There, You should also reset the `marginLeft` property... Else, the images will go to the left a bit more at each click and soon will be out of its container. There is nothing in your code to bring it to the right. So maybe it's the place to reposition it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 imageCounter = 0;
 
  $("#image_list a").each(function() {
    // get the image URL and caption for each image
    var imageURL = $(this).attr("href");
    var caption = $(this).attr("title");
    var slideNode = $("image_list");
    //var images = 


    // preload the image for each link  
    var galleryImage = new Image();
    galleryImage.src = imageURL;

    // set up the event handlers for each link
    $(this).click(function(evt) {
      
      $("#image").animate({
        marginLeft: "-=100px",
      }, 2000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
        $("#caption").fadeOut(400);
        $("#image").fadeOut(400, function(){
          $(this).attr("src", imageURL).css({"marginLeft":0}).fadeIn(400);
          $("#caption").text(caption).fadeIn(400);
        });
        
        //load in next image after animation 
        imageCounter = (imageCounter + 1) % imageURL.length;  
      }); 

      // cancel the default action of each link
      evt.preventDefault();
    }); // end click 
  }); // end each
  
  // move the focus to the first link
  $("li:first-child a").focus();
}); // end ready
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 420px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}
h1, h2, ul, p {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
h1 {
 padding-bottom: .25em;
 color: blue;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 120%;
 padding: .5em 0;
}
li {
 padding: 0 0.25em;
 display: inline;
}
#caption, #gallery {
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Image Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="image_gallery.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<main>
    <h1>Image Gallery</h1>
    <ul id="image_list">
        <li><a href="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=casting1.jpg" title="Casting on the Upper Kings">Upper Kings</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=casting2.jpg" title="Casting on the Lower Kings">Lower Kings</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=catchrelease.jpg" title="Catch and Release on the Big Horn">Big Horn</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=fish.jpg" title="Catching on the South Fork">South Fork</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=lures.jpg" title="The Lures for Catching">Lures</a></li>
    </ul>
    <h2 id="caption">Casting on the Upper Kings</h2>
    <p id="gallery">
     <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?text=casting1.jpg" alt="Image Gallery area" id="image">
    </p>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice that jQuery was not loaded in the snippet of your question... And the `imageCounter` was not defined with an initial value.